# MySQL Query for getting records with reference to records of related table with condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying a query to get specific results, but getting no luck.

Can any one help me in solving my problem. Here I am describing what exactly I need.

I have three tables, 
**Projects:** contains the project details. Each project can have different version. So the same projects with different versions have same jobNo. Only one version of a project i.e. the latest version is always live and other versions are archive.
**Users:** Contains the user details who exists in the system.
**Assigned Users:** This table contains the information of which users assigned to which project.

Here is the image of my db design.
[image]

I need a query in which I want the lists of live projects where the user "aaaa" is assigned either to the live version of the project or assigned to previous versions of the project.
For Ex: from the image, it should show me the project (id = 2, jobNo = 100) as it is live version. Though the aaaa is not assigned to V2 version, but it is assigned to V1 version of same project.

Hope I am clear with my problem.

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Can you please show the output which you want to see for `aaaa`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check below query if it helps you.

```
SELECT pr.id, pr.jobNo 
FROM project pr 
JOIN (SELECT jobNo 
      FROM user_table u 
      JOIN Assign_User a ON u.id=a.F_userID 
      JOIN project p ON p.id=a.F_projectID WHERE u.id=2) a 
ON pr.jobNo=a.jobNo 
WHERE pr.islive='Y';
```

Answer (score 1):

Earlier I didn't notice your bridge table sorry for that, this query should give you the correct result:

```
SELECT P . * 
    FROM project P
    WHERE id
    IN (
        SELECT MAX( id ) 
        FROM project
        GROUP BY jobNo
    )

    AND EXISTS (
    SELECT u.id AS userID
    FROM users u, assignedusers au, project p2
    WHERE p2.id = au.F_projectId
    AND au.F_userid = u.id
    AND u.userName LIKE  "aaaa"
    AND p2.name = P.name
    )
```

**NOTE: If you are going ahead with this DB design you are certainly gonna face many other issues ahead, I suggest you keep versions in a different table something like ProjectVersions which should have 1-Many relation 1 On Project side and Many on ProjectVersions side. Also make keep these v1, v2, v3 as version names and keep their int weight or a status for indicating `isLive` or something that way your queries will be quite easy to write.**

Comment: Hi pronox, Thanks for the solution. Yes I am agree with your suggestion. As this is an existing design, I can not change the db design. I am also facing many problems in development for this design.

Comment: @Gourav Welcome, Keep your confidence high then ;)